# URIBuilder build() cuts Port?

Tags: java, uri, uribuilder

I tried to build a URI using URIBuilder using a specific port and a key,value pair.

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
URI address        = builder.setScheme("http")
                        .setPath("127.0.0.1")
                        .setPort(12345)
                        .addParameter("key", "value")
                        .build();
System.out.println("BuilderPort is: " + builder.getPort());

System.out.println("URIPort is: " + address.getPort();
```

Console showing:

```
BuilderPort is: 12345
URIPort is: -1
```

Is this a wanted behavior? I know I can use:

```
public URI(String scheme, String userInfo, String host, int port, String path, String query, String fragment)
```

I wondering for .setPort() method if it will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *setPath()* you have to use *setHost("127.0.0.1")* (or in this case *setHost("localhost")*).